# Writing out comma separated values in a single cell in spreadsheet

Tags: python, csv

I am cataloging attribute fields for each feature class in the input list, below, and then I am writing the output to a spreadsheet for the occurance of the attribute in one or more of the feature classes.

```
import arcpy,collections,re  
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True  
input = [list of feature classes]  
outfile= # path to csv file   
f=open(outfile,'w')   
f.write('ATTRIBUTE,FEATURE CLASS\n\n')  
mydict = collections.defaultdict(list)  
for fc in input:  
    cmp=[]  
    lstflds=arcpy.ListFields(fc)  
    for fld in lstflds:  
        cmp.append(fld.name)  
    for item in cmp:  
        mydict[item].append(fc)  
for keys, vals in mydict.items():  
    #remove these characters  
    char_removal = ["[","'",",","]"]  
    new_char = '[' + re.escape(''.join(char_removal)) + ']'  
    v=re.sub(new_char,'', str(vals))  
    line=','.join([keys,v])+'\n'  
    print line  
    f.write(line)  
f.close()
```

This code gets me 90% of the way to the intended solution. I still cannot get the feature classes(values) to separate by a comma within the same cell(being comma delimited it shifts each value over to the next column as I mentioned). In this particular code the "v" on line 20(feature class names) are output to the spreadsheet, separated by a space(" ") in the same cell. Not a huge deal because the replace " " with "," can be done very quickly in the spreadsheet itself but it would be nice to work this into the code to improve reusability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import arcpy,collections,re,csv
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
input = [# list of feature classes]
outfile= # path to output csv file
f=open(outfile,'wb')
csv_write=csv.writer(f)
csv_write.writerow(['Field','Feature Class'])
csv_write.writerow('')
mydict = collections.defaultdict(list)
for fc in input:
    cmp=[]
    lstflds=arcpy.ListFields(fc)
    for fld in lstflds:
        cmp.append(fld.name)
    for item in cmp:
        mydict[item].append(fc)
for keys, vals in mydict.items():
    # remove these characters
    char_removal = ["[","'","]"]
    new_char = '[' + re.escape(''.join(char_removal)) + ']'
    v=re.sub(new_char,'', str(vals))
    csv_write.writerow([keys,""+v+""])
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

For a CSV file, use double-quotes around the cell content to preserve interior commas within, like this:

```
content1,content2,"content3,contains,commas",content4
```

Generally speaking, many libraries that output CSV just put all contents in quotes, like this:

```
"content1","content2","content3,contains,commas","content4"
```

As a side note, I'd strongly recommend using an existing library to create CSV files instead of reinventing the wheel.  One such library is [built into Python 2.6+](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html).

As they say, "Good coders write.  Great coders reuse."

Comment: I'm not sure if you took the time to rerun the code on your end to see the output that is produced. Simply wrapping quotes around does not solve the problem. I passed the "v" object into the writer in the form of ""+v+"". still shifting the values over into the next column in the output.

Comment: Because the variable "input" isn't clearly defined, it's not possible to run your code as-is to see exactly your output.  Can you copy into your question one line from your output file where the fields are being shifted, specifying what you expect to be in each field and what is actually in each field?

Comment: Actually, just got it to work, i will post it for anyone that may benefit. I had the right syntax but actually have to use the csv module to pass in the "v" object as a string into the writer. Otherwise, it does not work. Thanks for the helpful hint.